# Adding random rows within a group in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, measurement

I would like to know how to create the last column, Audit. To determine whether it is Included or Not Included the sum of any rows in "Average meeting per Day" within the same Employee/Day should match the "Actual Meeting" the employee attended.

[image]

Comment: Are we supposed to add up all the combinations of Average/Meeting/Day until we find those that add to ActualMeeting?

Comment: Yes, all possible combinations.

Comment: Assumption - Actual Meeting is same for same day same emp ID and emp name??

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is going to help, but here goes. Note: not set up to work with duplicate values among the potential items to analyze. No idea if it will work with so many decimals, so that the sum of the decimals might be 0.0000001 off from total and thus not be recognized. Works for me with whole numbers

```
let
Process=(x as table) as table =>
//  Bill Szysz 2017, all combinations of items in list, blows up with too many items to process due to large number of combinations
let ComboList=x[AMD],
find=x[AM]{0},
Source=Table.FromList(List.Transform(ComboList, each Text.From(_))),
AddIndex = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1),
ReverseIndeks = Table.AddIndexColumn(AddIndex, "RevIdx", Table.RowCount(AddIndex), -1),
Lists = Table.AddColumn(ReverseIndeks, "lists", each 
  List.Repeat(
      List.Combine({
           List.Repeat({[Column1]}, Number.Power(2,[RevIdx]-1)),
           List.Repeat(   {null}, Number.Power(2,[RevIdx]-1))
   })
, Number.Power(2, [Index]))
),
ResultTable = Table.FromColumns(Lists[lists]),
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(ResultTable,null,"0",Replacer.ReplaceValue,Table.ColumnNames(ResultTable )),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Replaced Value", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
totals = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each  List.Sum(List.Transform(Record.ToList( Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Index",Table.ColumnNames(ResultTable )){[Index]}) , each Number.From(_)))),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(totals, each ([Custom] = find)),
#"Kept First Rows" = Table.FirstN(#"Filtered Rows",1),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Kept First Rows", {"Custom", "Index"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", each ([Value] <> "0")),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows1",{"Value"}),
FoundList = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Other Columns",{{"Value", type number}}),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(x, {"AMD"}, FoundList, {"Value"}, "output1", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded output1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "output1", {"Value"}, {"Value"}),
#"Calculated Absolute Value" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Expanded output1",{{"Value", each if _=null then "Not Included" else "Included", type text}})
in #"Calculated Absolute Value",

Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Day", type text}, {"Employee_ID", Int64.Type}, {"AM", Int64.Type}, {"AMD", Int64.Type}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Day", "Employee_ID"}, {{"data", each _, type table [Day=nullable text, Employee_ID=nullable number, AM=nullable number, AMD=nullable number]}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each Process([data])),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Custom"}),
#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Custom", {"Day", "Employee_ID", "AM", "AMD", "Value"}, {"Day", "Employee_ID", "AM", "AMD", "Value"})
in
#"Expanded Custom"
```

[image]

Comment: I'll check about this solution. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've taken this as an Example dataset -
[image]

Further, use Group By and Conditional column to have the Audit added.

Group by -
[image]

Conditional Column -
[image]

Result -
[image]

Code -

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45W8s3PS0msVNJRMgRiAz1TMGkEJBOVYnVwSBtjShuBJQzhZBJYOqQ0tRhZuwlcHqg9=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Day = _t, Emp_ID = _t, #"Actual Meeting" = _t, #"Average Meeting/Day" = _t, Emp_Name = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Day", type text}, {"Emp_ID", Int64.Type}, {"Actual Meeting", type number}, {"Average Meeting/Day", type number}, {"Emp_Name", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Day", "Emp_ID"}, {{"Sum of avg", each List.Sum([#"Average Meeting/Day"]), type nullable number}, {"Actual Meeting", each List.Min([Actual Meeting]), type nullable number}}),
    #"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Audit", each if [Actual Meeting] = [Sum of avg] then "Included" else "Not Included")
in
    #"Added Conditional Column"
```

Comment: Code doesnt seem to work for me (error on the binary decompress).  I was under the impression to idea was to see which parts out of many added to a specific total. Is that what your code is doing?

Comment: Hi, I intentionally changed the encrypted text as I've manually input text data source, but main logic I've explained above. Moreover, the Last two lines of the code are the main logic for it. First is the group by statement and then conditional column.

Comment: Got it. The code was not meant to work.